# SQL Server: Using COUNT with IN and NOT IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a data table as follows :

```
file_id | action code
  1     |     10
  1     |     20
  2     |     10
  2     |     12
  3     |     10
  3     |     20
  4     |     10
  4     |     10
  4     |     20
```

The output is:

```
file_id | Warning
  1     |   0
  2     |   0  <- this should be 1 instead
  3     |   0
  4     |   1
```

The first count works as expected, and sets warning as 1, if there are any action_code duplicates, but i can't get it to work and display a warning if action_code is not perfectly divisible with 10

```
     @exported [int] = NULL,
 @bin_id [int] = NULL,
 @date_start [DateTime],
 @date_stop  [DateTime],
 @action_code  [int] = NULL,
 @action_description [varchar](43) = NULL

SELECT 
    dbo.Tf.file_id AS 'ID', 
    dbo.Tf.file_name AS 'NAME', 
    MAX(dbo.TFD.action_date) AS 'DATE', 
    MAX(dbo.TFD.file_length) AS 'SIZE', 
    dbo.Bins.name AS 'BIN',
    dbo.TFD.action_description, 

    CASE
    WHEN (COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.TFD.action_code) <> COUNT(dbo.TFD.action_code) )
    AND
    ((SELECT COUNT ( dbo.TFD.action_code ) FROM TFD WHERE action_code IN (10,20,30,40,50))  > 0
     AND
    (SELECT COUNT ( dbo.TFD.action_code ) FROM TFD WHERE action_code NOT IN (10,20,30,40,50))  > 0 ) THEN 1         
    ELSE 0 
    END AS 'Warning'            
FROM
(    SELECT
     dbo.Tf.file_id,
     MAX(dbo.TFD.action_code) AS 'action_code'

     FROM Tf 
     INNER JOIN TFD 
     ON Tf.file_id = TFD.file_id INNER JOIN Bins ON Tf.bin_id = Bins.bin_id

     WHERE
     (@bin_id IS NULL OR Tf.bin_id = @bin_id) 
      AND Tf.file_id IN 
                    (
                    SELECT H.file_id 
                    FROM Tf AS H INNER JOIN TFD AS D  ON H.file_id = D.file_id 
                    WHERE ((D.action_date >= @date_start AND D.action_date <= @date_stop) OR (H.file_date >= @date_start AND H.file_date <= @date_stop)) 
                    AND (H.bin_id = @bin_id OR @bin_id IS NULL) 
                    AND H.file_type = @exported 
                    AND ((@action_description IS NULL) OR (D.action_description LIKE @action_description + '%'))
                    )
      AND (@exported IS NULL OR Tf.file_type = @exported)

      GROUP BY dbo.Tf.file_id) AS TempSelect

 INNER JOIN Tf 
      ON Tf.file_id = TempSelect.file_id 
 INNER JOIN TFD 
      ON (TFD.file_id = TempSelect.file_id 
      AND TFD.action_code = TempSelect.action_code)
 INNER JOIN Bins ON Tf.bin_id = Bins.bin_id
 WHERE
   (
   (@action_code IS NULL ) OR (@action_code <> -1  AND TempSelect.action_code = @action_code) 
   OR (@action_code = -1 AND TempSelect.action_code NOT IN (10,20,30,40) )
   )
    GROUP BY
    dbo.Tf.file_id, 
    dbo.Tf.file_name, 
    dbo.Bins.name,
    dbo.Tf.bin_id,
    dbo.TFD.action_description
```

EDIT: I added the whole procedure. My main goal,among others, is to set the field warning as 1 if the following conditions are met:

1. if there are any action_code duplicates (as it's the case for file 4)
2. if there is an action_code not divisible by 10 among the other action_codes for each file (as it's the case with file 2)

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide the logic you are trying to implement?  Clearly, non-working SQL code is not necessary going to convey what you really want to do.

Comment: What is the logic for id 2 to get 'warning'?

Answer (score 1):

If your logic is:  Set a flag to 1 if there are duplicates or if a code is not divisible by 10, then I would suggest:

```
select (case when count(distinct d.action_code) <> count(*) then 1
             else max(case when d.action_code % 10 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end)
        end)
```

Notice that I replaced `dbo.Detail` with the table alias `d`.  Table aliases make a query easier to write, read, and understand.

Comment: That does not seem to work. It finds all of the files that have duplicates , but not the ones that have action_code <> 10,20,30,40 etc

Comment: @DanielD. . . . If any action code does not end in a 0, then the `when` condition should find it and return 1.  Aggregated over all rows this should be "1", which is what is desired.  Is `action_code` an integer?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
SELECT FILE_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN action_code % 10 != 0 THEN 1 END) not_divisible,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*)!=COUNT(DISTINCT action_Code) THEN 1 END not_unique
FROM #test
GROUP BY FILE_ID
```

Putting it all together you can use:

```
SELECT file_id,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*)!=COUNT(DISTINCT action_Code) THEN 1
         ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN action_code % 10 != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END Warning
FROM #test
GROUP BY file_id
```

Comment: That does not seem to work, it does the same thing as the above answer, which is getting half-way there

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query..

```
CREATE TABLE #t (FileID INT,ActionCode INT)

INSERT INTO #t
VALUES (1,10),(1,20),(2,10),(2,12),(3,10),(3,20),(4,10),(4,10),(4,20)

WITH cte_1
as (
SELECT *,COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY FileID,ActionCode ORDER BY fileID,ActionCode) CNT
FROM #T)

SELECT  FileID,case WHEN SUM(ActionCode) %10 <>0 THEN 1 WHEN MAX(CNT)<>1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM CTE_1
GROUP BY FileID
```

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answers, they were helpful, i modified the following section as such, and now it works:

```
...
    dbo.TFD.action_description,
     CASE  
     WHEN (COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.TFD.action_code) <> COUNT(dbo.TFD.action_code)) OR err_ac > 0
     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Warning'

FROM
( 
     SELECT
     dbo.Tf.file_id,
     MAX(dbo.TFD.action_code) AS 'action_code',
     CASE
     WHEN SUM(dbo.TFD.action_code) %10 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'err_ac'
...
```